# Partitioned table not optimizing the query of ranges of timecols

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I have a table for statuses of lots of things on PostgreSQL13.

Because of the number of objects I am keeping tabs on I decided to partition my table into years. According to the pgconf-eu-2019 conference from Postgres 12:

> Performance has been improved significantly by rewriting various pieces of code to process only the partitions that are needed by a query. So where previously, single-record queries would run in the amount of time that is proportional to the number of partitions, that is no longer the case.

However when I analyse my query I am finding that table performance is significantly slowed by PostgreSQL scanning each of the child partition tables:

[image: Results form explain analyze, cost, verbose, buffers]

Can anyone shed light on why this is the case? A query that should take just a few seconds is timing out my application. Have I misconfigured something? See:

[image: Table description]

as an example of a culprit query...

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
select  "videos"."id", "videos"."size", "videos"."name" as file, cast("videos"."duration" as integer), extract(epoch from "videos"."start_timestamp") as start_time,extract(epoch from  "videos"."end_timestamp")as end_time,"videos"."active", "statuses"."name" as status  
from 
  "videos"
left join "statuses" on ("statuses"."model_type" = 'App\Models\Video') and ("statuses"."created_at" between '2020-05-01T00:00:00' and '2021-05-02T23:59:59' )  
where "statuses"."id" = 
(
  select    max("id")
  from    "statuses"
  where   "statuses"."model_id" = "videos"."id") 
  and "videos"."vessel_id" = 26 and "videos"."device_id" = 104   
  and "videos"."end_timestamp" >= '2020-05-01T00:00:00' 
  and "videos"."start_timestamp" <= '2021-05-02T23:59:59'
  group by 
    "videos"."start_timestamp", 
    "videos"."end_timestamp", 
    "videos"."size", "videos"."id", 
    "videos"."duration", 
    "videos"."name", "videos"."active", 
    "statuses"."name"
  order by "videos"."start_timestamp"
);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se. Please don't use images here if possible for the reasons outlined in this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530).

Comment: Your query has a syntax error, unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

To get partition pruning, it must be easy for the database to determine which partitions to scan. Essentially, you need a `WHERE` condition in the query that restricts the partitioning key. Your query doesn't have that.

To be honest, I cannot understand your query at all. You write `LEFT JOIN` but then turn it into an inner join with the condition on `statuses.id`. And the subquery leaves me mystified.

Make sure that any query on `statuses` has `WHERE created_at =/</>/BETWEEN` in it.